# jquery: hide/show based on variable for class name

Tags: jquery, class, filter, show-hide

I am pretty new to jQuery and need some help with filtering classes. The user can choose from nine buttons to select which event types to show/hide. Click a color and only events with that color show and the rest are hidden. Click "all" and all events show with none hidden. All events start out with `display:block`.

Example control buttons:

```
<li class="all" id="all-events"><a href="#" onclick="showEvents('event-all')">
<img src="swatch-all.png" alt="" /></a></li>

<li class="red" id="red-events"><a href="#" onclick="showEvents('event-red')">
<img src="swatch-red.png" alt="" /></a></li>

<li class="blue" id="blue-events"><a href="#" onclick="showEvents('event-blue')">
<img src="swatch-blue.png" alt="" /></a></li>
```

The events are pulled from a database by php and look like this example:

```
<div id="bigCal">
    <p class="all"><a href="http://foo.com" title="All event">All events</a></p>
    <p class="blue"><a href="http://bar.com" title="Blue event">Blue event</a></p>
    <p class="red"><a href="http://foobar.com" title="Red event">Red event</a></p>
</div>
```

I've been working on the jQuery for two days! Not sure whether to use `.filter` or `.hasClass` or `.is`. None of it works. The simplest I tried was:

```
function showEvents(color) {
    ($('p').hasClass(color)) ? this.style.display="block" : this.style.display="none";
}
```

Another attempt that did nothing was

```
function showEvents(color){
    $("p[className*='event-']").css('display', 'none');
    $("p[className=color]").css('display', 'block');
    if ($("p[className='event-all']")) 
        $("p[className*='event-']").css('display', 'block');
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/YnFWX/1/

I am not using images, but you will get the idea. Notice that I am not assigning javascript by using the 'onclick' event. Much cleaner if you do it via jQuery.

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Excellent! By adding the "all" class to every color (class="all red"), that makes it easy to show all. That had me totally stumped--how to get all of the other classes easily. Thanks! Plus learning about jsfiddle.net. How cool is that!

Comment: That code for getting the onclick through jQuery was really useful, too. Thanks for testing it out for me. Made all the difference and it was so easy to implement it on my site.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showEvents(color){
var csscol=color.split('-')[1];//will return red/blue/all from event-red/event-blue/event-all
$('p[class!=' + csscol + ']').hide(); //hide all not equal to csscol
$('p[class=' + csscol + ']').show(); //show all equal to csscol
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I've asked a question on this forum and I am really impressed with the useful responses that arrived so fast! Thank you, all of you!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you seem to be passing "event-all" into `showEvents` instead of just "all".

So if you change your `onclick` code to `showEvents('all'), showEvents('blue')`, etc... it should work.

However, I'd approach this differently. It's far easier to assign your onclick handlers using jQuery in the first place, and find out the color that was clicked within this handler by looking at the class on the `<li>`, rather than passing it in.

```
// The is the same as onclick=.... but for ALL <a> elements within an <li>
$("li > a").click(function () {

   // Find the color that was clicked
   var color = $(this).parent().attr("class");

   // "All" is a special case
   if (color == "all") {
      // Show all <p>s in div with ID "bigCal"
      $("#bigCal p").show();
   } else {
      // Hide all <p>s in div with ID "bigCal"
      $("#bigCal p").hide();

      // Show the <p> with the same class
      $("#bigCal p." + color).show();
   }

});
```

Comment: You're right that finding the clicked button using jQuery. It is a lot cleaner. ^_^ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I have for you. I changed your onclick calls to reflect the actual name of your classes.

**Javascript**

```
function showEvents(color) {
         if(color!='all')
         {
            jQuery('#bigCal > p').hide();
            jQuery('.'+color).show();
         }
         else{jQuery('#bigCal > p').show();}
      }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
      <li class="all" id="all-events">
        <a href="#" onclick="showEvents('all')">Show All</a>
      </li>
      <li class="red" id="red-events">
        <a href="#" onclick="showEvents('red')">Show Red</a>
      </li>
      <li class="blue" id="blue-events">
        <a href="#" onclick="showEvents('blue')">Show Blue</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   <div id="bigCal">
      <p class="all"><a href="http://foo.com" title="All event">All events</a></p>
      <p class="blue"><a href="http://bar.com" title="Blue event">Blue event</a></p>
      <p class="red"><a href="http://foobar.com" title="Red event">Red event</a></p>
   </div>
```

That said - I found Visual jQuery invaluable while I was learning jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/visual/

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Visual jQuery. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
function showEvents(color){
 if(color=='event-all'){
   $('p').css('display','block');
 }else{
   $('p').css('display','none');
   $('p.'+color.replace('event-','')).css('display','block');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showEvents(color){
    $(p["class^='event-'"]).each(function() {
       if(!this.hasClass(color))this.hide();//or .css(display:none;)
       else {this.show()};
})
```

I think this should be the solution if i understood your question correctly.
FJ